# How to create function which will count the number of letters in a word

Tags: haskell

```
stringLength :: String -> Int
stringLength = undefined
```

That's the function above

Comment: In cases like this try to use [hoogle](//www.haskell.org/hoogle). You can specify a type and it will show you a list of values that match it or are close to it. https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=String+-%3E+Int

Comment: Although I must admit that given that it doesn't show anywhere that `String` is just a type synonym for `[Char]` it's not really clear to a beginner that you can use the function `length` of type `[a] -> Int`.

Comment: @fghibellini: One thing that helps exploration, which I often recommend to beginners: the `:info`/`:i` command in GHCi. `:info String` gives `type String = [Char] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’`, a useful starting point. It’s handy for finding out where things are defined, what methods a typeclass has, and what the precedence of an operator is; although the output can be large/overwhelming if, say, there are a lot of instances of a class, or beginner-unfriendly implementation details (see: `:info $`).

Comment: Are all characters in a string *letters*?

Comment: Your function suggests that you want the *length* of the string, but the title suggests you want to count the letters of a word (?). The two are not completely equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `String` is just an alias for `[Char]`, which is a list of characters. So the `length` function already does what you need:

```
Prelude> length "hello"
5
```

You can write your own wrapper like this:

```
stringLength :: String -> Int
stringLength s = length s
```

But in this case, point-free style might be nicer:

```
stringLength :: String -> Int
stringLength = length
```

And that raises the question: why have such a function at all?

Comment: holy shit thank you man, just a first year cs student struggling with life

Comment: Can't help you with life, I'm afraid. If you're literally struggling with it, I would recommend to go talk to a professional! If it was just hyperbole along the lines of "struggling with programming, programming is life", I understand, and that's fine too :)

Comment: Hi additional question, what does the type Event in haskell mean?

Comment: Additional questions are best posted as new questions, rather than comments on unrelated questions! (Also, I don't know :))